# Unable to install moment.js using Nuget

Tags: asp.net, momentjs

I am trying to install moment.js in my ASP.NET webforms project but, I am getting the following error,

[image]

I don't think moment.js is anything to do with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.2'. I am wondering why this error is occurring and preventing me from installing the moment.js

Environment:
Visual Studio 2015
Windows 7 64 bit OS
ASP.NET Webforms project

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create an ASP Core project by mistake?

Comment: No, I did not. I am running this ASP.NET webforms application for last 6 months and now I am in a situation to include moment js. But, somehow it is failing.